# Django Meta Class - Apply Ordering to user's model field

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django 1.9, I have an models.py :

```
class MyProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    Role = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=1000), blank=True,null=True)
    ContactNumber = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date_joined',)
```

Here I want to order table using `date_joined` which is field of `User model`.

When I am trying to run `python manage.py makemigrations` it gives me error as follows:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
projectmanagement.UniservedTeam: (models.E015) 'ordering' refers to the non-existent field 'date_joined'.
```

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To set ordering on generic api views:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter

use: `ordering = ('user__date_joined', )`

EDIT:

you can specify ordering on meta class like this:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ('user__date_joined', )
```

Comment: Sorry but I want to order it inside model.

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'user' has no attribute 'date_joined'

Comment: Worked , Thanks !!

Comment: great! glad to be of help :)